# How to prove that the sequence of functions $f_{n}(x)=\ln \left( \frac{x}{n} + 1 \right)$ doesn't converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis

I've established that the sequence of functions $f_{n}(x)=\ln \left(\frac{x}{n} + 1 \right)$ converges point wise to the function constant zero.

Now I have to prove that it doesn't converge uniformly on $[0,\infty]$

I've concluded that: $\sup \left | f_{\infty }-f \right |_{x\in [0,\infty ]} = \sup_{x\in [0,\infty ]} \ln \left( \frac{x}{n} + 1 \right)$

The problem I'm having is that I think that this function doesn't have a supremum, it is increasing on the whole interval...

Am I right?

Can we prove that it isn't uniformly convergent any other way?

Comment: The supremeum is $\infty$ and  that proves that the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Because $ sup_{x\in [0,\infty ]} \ln (\frac{x}{n}+1)=+\infty$, then, yes, you are right, it cannot be uniform convergence.

Comment: If it converged uniformly, we would have $$
\lim_{n\to +\infty}\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \ge 0} \left| {\log \left( {\frac{x}{n} + 1} \right)} \right| = 0.
$$ However, $$
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \ge 0} \left| {\log \left( {\frac{x}{n} + 1} \right)} \right| \ge \left| {\log \left( {\frac{n}{n} + 1} \right)} \right| = \log 2 > 0.
$$